# BindableCollection in ContentPresenter

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I'm using a ContentPresenter (like a partial view in MVC) to display a simple list of (sub)view in the UserControl, but the data is not bound.

Tried the verbose version of data binding, also the one liner, but no data bound to the display.

The UserControl has a property, called WorkPieces which is a BindableCollection of WorkPieceViewModel, and instantiated on startup to have a default value of Width: 0, Length: 0 and a Designator (roman number).
The relevant part of the UserControl view:

```
<ContentPresenter Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" x:Name="WorkPieces" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:WorkPieceViewModel}">
            <local:WorkPieceView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
</ContentPresenter>
```

The WorkPieceView: (also a UserControl)

```
<DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="WorkPieceId" Visibility="Hidden" />

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="Designator" Text="{Binding Designator}" MinWidth="15"/>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Text="{x:Static lang:Resources.Txt_W}" />

        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" x:Name="WorkWidth" MinWidth="50"/>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" Text=" x " />

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5" Text="{x:Static lang:Resources.Txt_L}" />

        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="6" x:Name="WorkLength" MinWidth="50"/>

        <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="7" Margin="5">
            <Image Source ="/Images/plus-sign.png" Height="16" Width="16" />
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                    <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="AddNewWorkPiece" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Button>

        <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="8" Margin="5">
            <Image Source ="/Images/minus-sign.png" Height="16" Width="16" />
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                    <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="RemoveWorkPiece">
                        <cal:Parameter Value="{Binding ElementName=Id}" />
                    </cal:ActionMessage>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</DockPanel>
```

The main issue is the width and length values not bound.
I've got a few other issues, like the strech is not working - but that is just UI, the Designator is not displayed, although it has a value of 'I' (roman 1). This can be because of no binding happens.

Comment: have you try to write explicity the binding for WorkLength and WorkWidth, i am not sure caliburn do the job in that case?  if you have the project in github for example it will be easy to test it...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the overcomplication of the task. A simple ListBox with a BindingList solved my problem...